# Path of War Progression problem?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Currently a Rogue: Hidden Blade Lv12 and completed the giant invasion of Sandpoint portion of the Rune Lords PF game. Got enough EXP and Bonus EXP to gain 2 levels. I want to add the Stalker class to it. How do I calculate Initiator Level and Maneuver Progression? Does it stack? I wasn't sure since Hidden Blade is an Archetype and Stalker is a "core" POW class.

So do I add my levels in Rogue: Hidden Blade & Stalker levels to get the new total for Initiator Level?

Do I then just add the Hidden Blades's and Stalker's Maneuvers and Stances together to get the new total?

Answer (score 2):

As seen in the [Initiator Level](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/systems-and-use/#Initiator_Level) part of the *System and Use* section, each martial class has its Initiator level and **they both use their maneuvers separately**, with their separated "maneuver slots" (just like a Wizard/Cleric has to prepare their spells separately). That also means your character will have to ready its maneuvers twice, once for each class.

Your Hidden Blade has a Initiator level of (Hidden Blade level) + 1/2*(other class level), here 12+1/2*2 = 13.
As you only took levels in Stalker, you don't learn any Hidden Blade maneuvers for now.

Your Stalker has a Initiator level of 1+1/2*12 = 7 for its first level, and 2+1/2*12 = 8 for its second. In both cases, it gives you access to **Stalker** maneuvers up to level 4, but if you had started at level 10, you would only have had access to level 3 maneuvers for your first Stalker level.
You learn 6 maneuvers and 1 Stance, and then 1 more maneuver and 1 more Stance, all of level 4 or less.

Comment: Ok, so if get this right each class get their own Initiator Level, even though Hidden Blade is an archetype for the Rogue? Similar to having different spell sources divine, arcane, psionics.  So if I go 10 Rogue Hidden Blade and 4 Stalker Bushido via  retraining rules, my  Rogue HB Initiator Lv = 10+1/2 x 4 (12) with access to 5th Lv Maneuvers and Stalker Bushi  = 4+1/2 x 10 (9) with access to Lv 4  Maneuvers.

Comment: Yes Archetypes are variation of the "base" class, but are classes nonetheless. Also, be careful of the order of your construction, as initiator classes only gain new maneuvers when you take a level in them.

Comment: I'm sorry. Does that mean literally like keeping track of two separate set of  magic or power bases for being multiclass? Ex: a Wizard Bard having a book of spells for wizards spells and his allotment of spells per day, as well keeping track off his bard spells per day? They are independent of each other. Or to make it easier Psionic Bard, spells known & spells per day and Powers known and PP per day?

Comment: Literally two  separate sets, like a Wizard/Bard.